# Passing database object to remote Service ( on different process ) from my Activity

Tags: android, database, service, locked

I have remote service running and collecting traffic which writes to my database. In my application i also use that database to read and write data. Sometimes i get "database locked" exception. I am using singleton pattern for my database object, but even then that error shows up. I guess its because, since my service is in different process i need to create database instance in the service too, so there is two db objects. My question is, can it be done with passing the database object through AIDL using binder ? Any different approach or a good practice is welcome.